# git clone stopped working

Tags: git, clone, gnutls

I'm on Bunsenlabs (based on Debian-jessie). A few months ago I went to clone something and got:

```
git clone https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes.git
Cloning into 'gibberish-aes'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Public key signature verification has failed.
```

Even some of my existing repositories can't update

```
cd geoClock
git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/alexxroche/geoClock.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Public key signature verification has failed.
```

If there is nothing to update then pull and push work as expected.

git clone was something that I used daily. I checked that my ip{,6}tables isn't blocking me. No idea how I broke gnutls. I tried to get git to use openssl as a bypass, but when that didn't work I've been grabbing zip, (which is almost as good, but I still need to fix this.)

```
sudo aptitude search tls|grep ^i
i A libcurl3-gnutls - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
i  libcurl4-gnutls-dev - development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS flavour)
i  libgnutls-deb0-28 - GNU TLS library - main runtime library
i  libgnutls-openssl27 - GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
i A libgnutls30 - GNU TLS library - main runtime library
i A libneon27-gnutls - HTTP and WebDAV client library (GnuTLS enabled)
```

Any idea how I fix this?

Comment: Do you have package `libgnutls-deb0-28` installed? If so, could you try to uninstall it and retry cloning?

Comment: Thank you. After # `apt-get remove -y libgnutls-deb0-28; apt-get install -y curl feh ffmpeg git libreoffice mpd mpv ncmpcpp` clone works again!

Comment: Had an issue with accessing several https repositories (git and apt). Removing `libgnutls-deb0-28` solved it. Thanks @nKn