# git clone and apt error : gnutls_handshake() failed

Tags: linux, git, apt, debian-stretch, gnutls

When cloning a git repository using `git clone`, I get the following error :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/schacon/simplegit-progit/': 
gnutls_handshake() failed: Public key signature verification has failed
```

Additionally, I obtain a similar error when running `apt-get update` :

```
Err:12 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
gnutls_handshake() failed: Public key signature verification has failed.
```

It appears that removing the `libgnutls-deb0-28` package could solve the problem. It is suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1250527/git-clone-stopped-working). However, I'm not sure what this package is about and what depends on it. In addition, when I try `apt-get remove libgnutls-deb0-28`, it also removes a LOT of apparently unrelated packages, which I obviously do not want to remove.

Similar problems ha reported in various previous posts, but the reason(s) for theis error are never clear to me.

Does anyone understand the problem and could explain where it comes from ?

I am running Debian 9.2 (stretch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I had a version of `librtmp1` installed that was left over from deb-multimedia, which depended on `libgnutls-deb0-28`. It had a newer version number than the one in the official Debian repos.

After I downgraded `librtmp1` to the version listed on https://packages.debian.org/stretch/librtmp1 I could remove `libgnutls-deb0-28` without too many things being removed together with it.

So you could try this:

```
apt-get install librtmp1=2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-1+b1
apt-get remove libgnutls-deb0-28
```

See also my more detailed discussion of my problem here: https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/2483#issuecomment-401047201

For me it was useful to look up what other packages depend on a specific package:

```
apt-cache rdepends libgnutls-deb0-28
```

and also the other direction, what does a package depend on:

```
apt-cache depends librtmp1
```

Comment: It perfecly solved my problem, thank you. Also, your comment on https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/2483#issuecomment-401047201 is very clear, and I recommend it to anyone having similar problems with `libgnutls-deb-28`